# Confused about golang slice cap

Tags: go, slice

i have a question about slice cap,the code:

```
var slice []int
list := []int{1,2,3,4,5}
for _,item := range list {
    slice = append(slice, item)
}
fmt.Println(len(slice),cap(slice))
```

if item == 1: len(slice)=1,cap(slice)=1

if item == 2: len(slice)=2,cap(slice)= 1*2

if item ==3: len(slice) = 3,cap(slice) = 2*2

if item == 4:len(slice) = 4,cap(slice) = 4

if item == 5:len(slice) = 5,cap(slice) = 4*2

so the output:

len(slice) = 5,cap(slice) = 8

that's no problem,but when i change the code:

```
var slice []int
slice = append(slice,1,2,3,4,5)
fmt.Println(len(slice),cap(slice))
```

output:

len(slice) = 5,cap(slice) = 6

why cap(slice) = 6 ?

Comment: The language spec does not define explicitly what the append algorithm should do when cap is not large enough. Therefore it's up to the implementers of the Go runtime to decide how the cap will grow. And that implementation may change from version to version. If what you want is to understand that algorithm then all you have to do is read the source. If what you want is to argue against the rationale behind the implementation then you can try the go-nuts mailing list. As a counter example try `s := make([]int, 0, 4); fmt.Println(cap(append(s, 1,2,3,4,5)))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the algorithm of capacity calculation when appending in `func growslice(et *_type, old slice, cap int)` in [src/runtime/slice.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go) - line 162

```
    newcap := old.cap
    doublecap := newcap + newcap
    if cap > doublecap {
        newcap = cap
    } else {
        if old.cap < 1024 {
            newcap = doublecap
        } else {
            // Check 0 < newcap to detect overflow
            // and prevent an infinite loop.
            for 0 < newcap && newcap < cap {
                newcap += newcap / 4
            }
            // Set newcap to the requested cap when
            // the newcap calculation overflowed.
            if newcap <= 0 {
                newcap = cap
            }
        }
    }
```

> - First multiply the old slice capacity by 2. If the capacity after
>   multiplying by 2 is still less than the new slice capacity, then take
>   the new slice capacity (append multiple elems)
> - If the new slice is
>   less than twice the old slice capacity, multiply the old slice
>   capacity by 2
> - If the old slice capacity is greater than or equal to 1024, the new
>   slice capacity is multiplied by the old slice capacity by 1.25

Reference -

- [src/runtime/slice.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go)
- [capacity-growth-algorithm-after-golang-slice-append](https://developpaper.com/capacity-growth-algorithm-after-golang-slice-append/)